# Authorize .net CIM with recurring payment

Tags: php, authorize.net, recurring-billing, authorize.net-cim

I have a website where users do payment in *installments(recurring payments)*. And since I don't want to store the user's credit card/ account information in my database, I used *PCI compliance* for which I used **AUTHORIZE .NET Cim**.

I followed this [library](http://www.johnconde.net/blog/tutorial-integrate-the-authorize-net-cim-api-with-php/), where everything works fine for the first time i.e.

> 1. createCustomerProfile
> 2. createCustomerPaymentProfile
> 3. createCustomerProfileTransaction

For the first time transaction works and I get all the response :

```
responsecode, transactionid, authid.
```

*But how do I manage recurring payments with `customer id` or `customer payment id.`*

I have even set : `$cim->setParameter('recurringBilling',true);`

Here is the complete code :

```
require('AuthnetCIM.class.php'); // class that has all the functions

$cim = new AuthNetCim('*******', '**********', 'apitest');

// Step 1: create Customer Profile
// Create unique fake email address, description, and customer ID

// $email_address = 'user' . time() . '@domain.com';
$email_address = $row['custemail1'];
$description   = 'Monthly Membership No. ' . md5(uniqid(rand(), true));
$customer_id   = substr(md5(uniqid(rand(), true)), 16, 16);

$cardcvv = $_POST['cardcvv'];
$cardno = $_POST['cardno1'].$_POST['cardno2'].$_POST['cardno3'].$_POST['cardno4'];
$phone = $_POST['billphone_1'] . '-' . $_POST['billphone_2'] . '-' . $_POST['billphone_3'];

$cim->setParameter('email', $email_address);
$cim->setParameter('description', $description);
$cim->setParameter('merchantCustomerId', $customer_id);
$cim->createCustomerProfile();

// Get the profile ID returned from the request
if ($cim->isSuccessful())
{
      $profile_id = $cim->getProfileID();

      $query = "UPDATE orders SET cust_proid='$profile_id' where orderid='$orderid' LIMIT 1";
      $result = mysql_query($query) or die("The following error has occurred:<br>" . mysql_error());

      $responsenote = $cim->getResponseText();
      $authorization = $cim->getResponse();            
 }

 // Step 2: create Payment Profile      

 $cim->setParameter('customerProfileId', $profile_id);
 $cim->setParameter('billToFirstName', $_POST['cardname']);
 $cim->setParameter('billToAddress', $_POST['billaddress1']);
 $cim->setParameter('billToCity', $_POST['billcity']);
 $cim->setParameter('billToState', $_POST['billstate']);
 $cim->setParameter('billToZip', $_POST['billzip']);
 $cim->setParameter('billToCountry', 'USA');
 $cim->setParameter('billToPhoneNumber', $phone);
 $cim->setParameter('cardNumber', str_replace('-', '', $cardno));
 $cim->setParameter('expirationDate', $_POST['cardexpyy'].'-'.$_POST['cardexpmm']); // (YYYY-MM)

 $cim->createCustomerPaymentProfile();

 // Get the payment profile ID returned from the request
 if ($cim->isSuccessful())
 {
      $payment_profile_id = $cim->getPaymentProfileId();

      $query2 = "UPDATE orders SET cust_pay_proid='$payment_profile_id' where orderid='$orderid' LIMIT 1";
      $result2 = mysql_query($query2) or die("The following error has occurred:<br>" . mysql_error());

      $responsenote = $cim->getResponse();
      $authorization = $cim->getResponse();
  }

  elseif($cim->isError())
  {
        $responsenote = $cim->getResponse();
        $authorization = $cim->getResponse();
        $approvalstatus='Declined';
  }
  else 
  {
        // echo 'Invalid Card, payment pro id not generated'; 
        $responsenote = 'Invalid Card';
        $authorization = 'Declined';
        $approvalstatus='Declined';
  }

  // Step 4: Process a transaction
  $purchase_amount = '5';

  if($row['cust_pay_proid'] == '')
  {
      $payment_profile_id = $cim->getPaymentProfileId();
  }
  else {
       $payment_profile_id = $row['cust_pay_proid'];
  }

  // if getPaymentProfileId not created i.e invalid card/ or issue with payment
  if($payment_profile_id != '')
  {
       // Process the transaction
       $cim->setParameter('amount', $purchase_amount);
       $cim->setParameter('customerProfileId', $profile_id);
       $cim->setParameter('customerPaymentProfileId', $payment_profile_id);
       $cim->setParameter('cardCode', $cardcvv);

       $cim->setParameter('recurringBilling',true); // for recurring 
       $cim->createCustomerProfileTransaction('profileTransAuthCapture');

       // Get the payment profile ID returned from the request
       if ($cim->isSuccessful())
       {
            $auth_code = $cim->getAuthCode();
            $query3 = "UPDATE orders SET auth_code='$auth_code' where orderid='$orderid' LIMIT 1";
            $result3 = mysql_query($query3) or die("The following error has occurred:<br>" . mysql_error());

            $responsenote = $cim->getResponse();
            $authorization = $cim->getResponse();
            $transactionid=$cim->getTransactionID();
            $approvalstatus='Approved';
       }
       elseif($cim->isError())
       {
            $responsenote = $cim->getResponse();
            $authorization = $cim->getResponse();
            $approvalstatus='Declined';
       }
       else
       {
            $responsenote = 'Invalid Profile/payment id';
            $authorization = 'Declined';
            $approvalstatus='Declined';
       }
  }
  else
  {
       $responsenote = $cim->getResponse();
       $authorization = $cim->getResponse();
       $approvalstatus='Declined';
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot make or manage subscriptions through CIM as it only is a means for creating and managing payment accounts. The recurring billing flag only is a note that this payment account you created will be used for recurring billing. It doesn't actually setup a subscription.

So if you want to use this as a recurring billing system you need to write your own recurring billing engine to actually schedule and process payments.

Comment: Authorize.Net will be adding the ability to [create subscriptions using a customer profile](https://community.developer.authorize.net/t5/The-Authorize-Net-Developer-Blog/New-Customer-Profile-and-Recurring-Billing-Enhancements/bc-p/53156#M529) in an upcoming release.

Comment: @rhldr They will make a lot of people happy by doing that.

Comment: @JohnConde, how can that be achieved ? Since, I'm not storing the user's card info in my db. Can that not be managed in `createCustomerProfileTransaction()`